# Additional space around element not knowing where it comes from, it's not padding or margin

Tags: html, css, space

When I inspect my elements, the p and h3 have dashed line not enveloping my element to the end of the edge of the element like it's happening on the img element, I can't figure why..

There is a little extra more space between the element and dashed line on the p and h3 element vs the img element. Any suggestions what it is? It's not margin or padding. The red is additional space:

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjFRR.jpg)

Comment: it's line-height

Answer (score 0):

As Temani says..looks like line-height. It's set independently but naturally related to the font-size.

Answer (score 0):

You'r right awesome, thank you! The problem now is it's addinng to margin  or padding.. So when ill measure padding ill have more of it from the lineheight. If ill set padding 35px, 35+something will happen.